# How to stop paths appearing on a new line using an ItemsControl template

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have some XAML that looks like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PathStrings}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Path Stroke="Red" Data="{Binding}" StrokeThickness="5" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

I am binding a list of path data from a database. However, when this renders out, the paths appear to be on a new line (like they are encased in something else). 
I would really love to fix this. 

*Any suggestions?*

[image: This is with a stackpanel with Horizonal]
  This is with a stackpanel that is horizonal
[image: This is with a vertical stackpanel]

This is with a vertical stack panel

Hopefully this helps someone to help me? Thanks

Comment: Can you maybe post a screenshot which is describes your problem, and how it should look like?

Comment: They appear in new line because you're using StackPanel with vertical orientation. Not sure what you really want to accomplish, but if it's a one line output, use horizontal StackPanel orientation.

Comment: As you can see above, stackpanel set to horizontal and vertical. No difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it is as simple as using a Canvas as the ItemsPanelTemplate. That simple.